# How to query on git pull requests in TFS

Tags: git, tfs-2015, pull-request

We use Team Foundation Server 2015 with git. Our pull requests are normally linked to work items. How can I create a list of pull requests that lack linked work items? I tried to create a query in TFS, but to query on a pull request seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To could use [this REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#by-repository-id) to get all pull request under your repository.

```
GET  http://serverName:8080/tfs/MyCollection/_apis/git/repositories/9f504fb5-7168-49cb-9846-963fdfc3f2b1/pullRequests?api-version=3.0-preview
```

Then loop those pull request you get, use [this REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/work-items#get-items-linked-to-a-pull-request) to get workitems linked to a pull request. The above REST API will return the pull request id of each pull request.

```
GET http://v-tinmo-12r2:8080/tfs/MyCollection/_apis/git/repositories/9f504fb5-7168-49cb-9846-963fdfc3f2b1/pullRequests/15/workitems?resource=pullRequestWorkItems
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query on Pull Requests currently.

You would have to use the API, or you can request this feature on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com.

You can create a branch policy that enforces that Pull Requests have at least one work item linked to it.

[image]

You can easily block Pull Requests that dont have a Work Item association.